# Problem with pickle.load after creating model with Gen Algorithm

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pickle

With using Gen Algorithm I am creating a model with some layers, after what I am using script for Training model. There is an example of elmenets, contaning in file.pkl

`Layers for individual:

<keras.src.layers.attention.attention.Attention object at 0x0000022434098ED0>

<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340998D0>

<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x000002243409A410>

<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x000002243409BA10>

<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x000002243409B9D0>

<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340A5F90>

<keras.src.layers.rnn.lstm.LSTM object at 0x00000224340A6E10>

<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340AC650>

<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340AC450>

<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340A5ED0>

<keras.src.layers.regularization.dropout.Dropout object at 0x00000224340AC790>

<keras.src.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x00000224340AE750>

{'batch_size': 6821, 'validation_split': 0.4201392186482606, 'epochs': 5}`

Libraries used for Gen Algorithm

```
import pickle
import random
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Attention
import tensorflow as tf
```

Libraries used for training model

```
import pickle
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Dropout, Attention
```

Code for Gen Algorithm and saving file.pkl

```
def genetic_algorithm(population_size, num_generations, mutation_rate):
    population = [generate_individual() for _ in range(population_size)]
    best_fitness_scores = []
    i = 0;

    for generation in range(num_generations):
        fitness_scores = evaluate_population(population)
        best_individual = get_best_individual(population, fitness_scores)
        best_fitness_scores.append(max(fitness_scores))

        print(f"Generation {generation + 1}, Best Fitness: {max(fitness_scores)}, Best Individual: {best_individual}")
        save_individual(f'best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl',
                best_individual)
        parents = select_parents(population, fitness_scores)
        offspring = crossover(parents, population_size)
        mutated_offspring = mutate(offspring, mutation_rate)

        population = mutated_offspring  # Обновление списка population

    best_individual = get_best_individual(population, fitness_scores)
    best_fitness_scores.append(max(fitness_scores))

    print(f"Generation {num_generations}, Best Fitness: {max(fitness_scores)}, Best Individual: {best_individual}")

    return best_individual, best_fitness_scores

best_individual = genetic_algorithm(population_size, num_generations, mutation_rate)

save_individual(f'best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl',
        best_individual)

print(' ')
print("---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
print(' ')
```

Code for openning file.pkl

```
with open(f'individuals/best_individual_{variables["clines_time"]}.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    best_individual = pickle.load(f)
    best_individual = best_individual[0]
batch_size = best_individual[-1]['batch_size']
model = create_model_from_individual(best_individual)
validation_split = best_individual[-1].get('validation_split', 0.3)
```

At time I'm openning file there is an error:

`best_individual = pickle.load(f) ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers.core'`

I don't know how to fix it.

Already tried to reinstall all libraries for my enviroment. Upgrade pip. By the way, I used Gen algorithm on another server, not on my computer. Tried to use both keras lib (tensorflow.keras and just keras)